# Pgfplots - conditional style

Tags: pgfplots, conditionals, ifthenelse

I would like to create a conditional style for my `pgfplots` graph that would use this or that elementary style, based on an input value.

Here is an example of a conditional style depending on the value of numplots, the problem is that I don’t know how to implement the condition, because the `\numplots` command is not recognized in the `\ifthenelse{...}`. Is it possible to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, ifthen}

\pgfplotsset{
    MyList-1/.style={
        cycle list={
            red, mark=*\\
        },
    },
    MyList-2/.style={
        cycle list={
            blue, mark=*\\%
            red, mark=*\\%
        },
    },
    MyList-3/.style={
        cycle list={
            green, mark=*\\%
            red, mark=*\\%
            blue, mark=*\\%
        },
    },
    MyList-4/.style={
        cycle list={
            red, mark=*\\%
            black, mark=*\\%
            green, mark=*\\%
            purple, mark=*\\%
        },
    },
    MyList-5/.style={
        cycle multiindex* list={
            blue\\%
            yellow\\%
            orange\\%
            red\\%
            green\\%
            \nextlist
            mark=*\\
            mark=square*\\
        },
    },
    MyList-6/.style={
        cycle multiindex* list={
            teal\\%
            violet\\%
            red\\%
            magenta\\%
            blue\\%
            brown\\%
            \nextlist
            mark=*\\
            mark=square*\\
        },
    },
    MyListChoice/.code={%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\numplots}{1}}{MyList-1}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\numplots}{1}}{MyList-2}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\numplots}{1}}{MyList-3}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\numplots}{1}}{MyList-4}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\numplots}{1}}{MyList-5}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\numplots}{1}}{MyList-6}{
            }}}}}}
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[MyListChoice]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `/.is choice` key handler.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{MyList/.is choice,
    MyList/1/.style={
        cycle list={
            red, mark=*\\
        },
    },
    MyList/2/.style={
        cycle list={
            blue, mark=*\\%
            red, mark=*\\%
        },
    },
    MyList/3/.style={
        cycle list={
            green, mark=*\\%
            red, mark=*\\%
            blue, mark=*\\%
        },
    },
    MyList/4/.style={
        cycle list={
            red, mark=*\\%
            black, mark=*\\%
            green, mark=*\\%
            purple, mark=*\\%
        },
    },
    MyList/5/.style={
        cycle multiindex* list={
            blue\\%
            yellow\\%
            orange\\%
            red\\%
            green\\%
            \nextlist
            mark=*\\
            mark=square*\\
        },
    },
    MyList/6/.style={
        cycle multiindex* list={
            teal\\%
            violet\\%
            red\\%
            magenta\\%
            blue\\%
            brown\\%
            \nextlist
            mark=*\\
            mark=square*\\
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[MyList=2]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[MyList=4]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I was not aware of this feature. Is it possible to make the list selection automatic with something like `\pgfplotsset{MyListAutoChoice/. style={every axis plot/. style={MyList=\numplots } }}` ?

Comment: @BLegrand You can make it automatic but I doubt that you want to pass the key to `every axis plot`. `\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={MyList=\numplots}}` should work. Of course, you can make `every axis/.append style={MyList=\numplots}` a style on its own.